# Embed polyfill into target bundle with rollup.js?

Tags: npm, node-modules, rollup, rollupjs, polyfills

I'm trying to bundle a js library with rollup, in order to run it with Jint (a dotnet js runtime). The library uses the Worker api, which is not available in Jint, so I'm trying to bundle the library with a polyfill: https://www.npmjs.com/package/worker-polyfill.

This is the rollup configuration:

```js
import { nodeResolve } from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonJS from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import virtual from "@rollup/plugin-virtual";
import replace from "@rollup/plugin-replace";
import visualizer from "rollup-plugin-visualizer";
// Needed by fastfile
import { O_TRUNC, O_CREAT, O_RDWR, O_EXCL, O_RDONLY } from "constants";

const empty = "export default {}";
// We create a stub with these constants instead of including the entire constants definition
const constants = `
export const O_TRUNC = ${O_TRUNC};
export const O_CREAT = ${O_CREAT};
export const O_RDWR = ${O_RDWR};
export const O_EXCL = ${O_EXCL};
export const O_RDONLY = ${O_RDONLY}
`;

export default {
    input: "main.js",
    output: {
        file: "build/snarkjs.js",
        format: "iife",
        globals: {
            os: "null"
        },
        name: "snarkjs"
    },
    plugins: [
        virtual({
            fs: empty,
            os: empty,
            crypto: empty,
            readline: empty,
            ejs: empty,
            events: empty,
            stream: empty,
            util: empty,
            constants: constants,
        }),
        nodeResolve({
            browser: true,
            preferBuiltins: false,
            exportConditions: ["browser", "default", "module", "require"],
            dedupe: ['worker-loader']
        }),
        commonJS(),
        replace({
            // The current default is false, but they are changing it next version
            preventAssignment: false,
            "process.browser": !!process.env.BROWSER
        }),
        visualizer(),
    ]
};
```

In main.js I added `export { Worker } from "worker-loader"`;

The bundle I obtain tough define a function that require workerLoader as input:

```js
var snarkjs = (function (exports, workerLoader) {
......
})({}, workerLoader);
```

How I can configure rollup to embed worker-loaded module instead? Thanks in advance.

For reference, this is the librari I'm trying to bundle in a single js: https://github.com/iden3/snarkjs/